# Динамическое меню c подгрузкой из json. Необходимо подгружать список дочерних пунктов в новый col-sm-2

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap, меню

Имеется json файл из которого должно формироваться меню.

HTML меню выглядит вот так:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown menu-large sys-menu" id="0010">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Системное меню<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
                            <li class="col-sm-2 level-1">
                                <ul class="level-1">
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-sm-2 level-2">
                                <ul class="level-2">
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-sm-2 level-3">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Input groups</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Basic example</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sizing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Checkboxes and radio addons</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Navs</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Tabs</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pills</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Justified</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-sm-2 level-4">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Navbar</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Default navbar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Non-nav links</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Component alignment</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fixed to top</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fixed to bottom</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Static top</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Inverted navbar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Вот JS скрипт, который написал я:

```
$.getJSON('../static/js/test_nav.json', function(data) {
var link = function findAllChildren (number) {
        var childs = {};
        var items = {};
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var item = data[i];
            var parentid = item["PARENT"];
            var url = item ["LINK"];
            var label = item ["NAME"];
            var id = item["CID"];
            if (parentid == number) {
                items[id] = {parentid:parentid, id:id, url:url, label:label};
                childs[id] = items[id];
            }
        }
        return childs;
    }


    var buildA = function (parent, items) {
        $.each(items, function () {
            if (this.label) {
                var a = $("<li id='"+ this.id +"' class='" + "specify" + "'>" + "<a href='"+ "#" +"' id='"+ this.id +"' class='" + "specify" + "'>" + this.label + "</a></li>");
                a.appendTo(parent);
            }
        })
    };

    $("li.sys-menu").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var source = link("" + id);
        $(document).find("li.level-1").append(buildA("ul.level-1", source))
        $("a.specify").click(function () {
            var id2 = $(this).attr('id');
            var source2 = link("" + id2);
            $(document).find("li.level-2").append(buildA("ul.level-2", source2))
        })
    });

});


$('ul.dropdown-menu.megamenu.row').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Я так понимаю, что проблема возникает с формированием меню по id.
В участке кода где я прописываю событие на клик:

```
$("li.sys-menu").click(function){...}
```

Переменная id2 вытаскивается. Но почему-то функция link не обрабатывает по второму кругу. В чём моя проблема? Что я не так делаю?

Задача: из списка формируется меню по parentid. Сформированный список имеет линки, которые по клику, должны формировать следующее дочернее меню. ID вытаскивается по клику линка. Каждый новый список формируется в следующем "col-sm-2 level-#"

P.S. Я понимаю, что тут видимо, необходимо использовать рекурсию, но мои навыки в JS скудны, и я просто не понимаю, как сделать это правильно. Буду признателен если поможете хоть как-то